# Creating dump file in tomcat folder

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jvm

When I stop the tomcat service, it creates huge `hs_err_pid6636.mdmp` and `hs_err_pid6636.log` files.

Full product version :

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Full OS version :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
```

Extra relevant system configuration :

```
Windows 2012 R2 standard,Oracle 12c ,Tomcat 8.

Dump file location: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\hs_err_pid1832.mdmp
```

In Log file:

Expected versus actual behavior :

```
should not generate error files(hs_err_pid1832.mdmp,hs_err_pid1832.log) in tomcat.
```

Error messages/stack traces that occur :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000742f3643, pid=1832, tid=5720
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x2d3643]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\hs_err_pid1832.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
.
.
.
.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.17056)

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8388152k(4594380k free), swap 9698872k(5318672k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_40-b25), built on Feb 10 2015 21:53:57 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue Apr 04 07:57:24 2017
elapsed time: 4117 seconds (0d 1h 8m 37s)
```

Comment: check the catalina log files under `{CATALINA}/logs/catalina.out`, and look for the latest exception if any before it reaches this fatal error. Do you use any native code in your context?

Comment: Thanks You for your quick response 
i cant find any error in catalina.out file
Below error i found in common-daemon.log file under log folder
[2017-04-18 01:28:49] [info]  [ 4848] Stopping service...
[2017-04-18 01:28:49] [error] [ 3420] FindClass org/apache/catalina/shutdown/Bootstrap failed
[2017-04-18 01:28:49] [error] [ 4848] Failed starting java
[2017-04-18 01:29:49] [info]  [ 4848] Service stop thread completed.

Comment: These kind of fatal errors are becasue of mixed native work(again make sure the native is bugfree if applicable) or jvm itself. keep the OS update might help too.